# Show that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}e^{-x}(e^{-x}-1)\mathrm dx$ diverges

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to prove that the integral 
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}e^{-x}(e^{-x}-1)dx$$ 
diverges?

I have tried to reduce the integral to the problem of harmonic series but I did not get any result.

Comment: Try to solve the integral by substituting $(\mathrm{e}^{-x}-1) = t$ and then apply by part theorem.

Comment: The integral as written is finite.

Comment: Do you have an extra $e^{-x}$ in the integrand?

Comment: I still do not know how to compute...

Comment: modified it to correct terminology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite easy:

1) Use the substitution: $e^x = t$, the integral will take form:

$$
\int_e^\infty \frac{1-t}{t^3 \ln t} dt = \int_e^\infty \frac{1}{t^3 \ln t} dt - \int_e^\infty \frac{1}{t^2 \ln t} dt
$$

2) The first integral converges, it is obvious, as $\int_e^\infty \frac{1}{t^3 \ln t}dt \leqslant  \int_e^\infty \frac{1}{t^3} dt \in \mathbb{R}$.

3) The second integral converges too.

Both integrals converge ergo the sum converges. The integral above is really finite.

Comment: You forgot that $dx = d(\log t) = \frac1t\,dt$. The integral as written is finite.

Comment: You are right, I forgot the 1/t.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

\begin{align}
&
\int_{1}^{\infty}{1 \over x}\,\pars{\expo{-2x} - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
=
\left.\ln\pars{x}\pars{\expo{-2x} - \expo{-x}}\right\vert_{1}^{\infty}
-
\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\pars{-2\expo{-2x} + \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\pars{2\expo{-2x} - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
\end{align}

Let's consider
$\ds{%
\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\pars{2\expo{-2x} - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
}$:

\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\pars{2\expo{-2x} - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
&=
{1 \over 2^{\mu}}\int_{2}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
-
\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2^{\mu}}\,\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1,2} - \Gamma\pars{\mu + 1,1}
\end{align}

$\Gamma\pars{z,\alpha}$ is the $\it\mbox{Incomplete Gamma function}$. We take derivatives, in both members, respect of $\mu$:
\begin{align}
&
\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\ln\pars{x}\pars{2\expo{-2x} - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
-\,{\ln\pars{2} \over 2^{\mu}}\,\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1,2}
+
{1 \over 2^{\mu}}\,
\left.\partiald{\Gamma\pars{\mu',2}}{\mu'}\right\vert_{\mu'\ =\ 1 + \mu}
-
\left.\partiald{\Gamma\pars{\mu',1}}{\mu'}\right\vert_{\mu'\ =\ 1 + \mu}
\end{align}

We'll take the limit $\mu \to 0$:
\begin{align}
&\int_{1}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\pars{2\expo{-2x} - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
=
-\ln\pars{2}\,\overbrace{\Gamma\pars{1,2}}^{\ds{\expo{-2}}}
+
\overbrace{%
\left.\partiald{\Gamma\pars{\mu',2}}{\mu'}\right\vert_{\mu'\ =\ 1}
-
\left.\partiald{\Gamma\pars{\mu',1}}{\mu'}\right\vert_{\mu'\ =\ 1}
}^{\ds{\Gamma\pars{0,2} - \Gamma\pars{0,1} +\expo{-2}\ln\pars{2}}}
\end{align}

where
$\ds{%
\Gamma\pars{0,2} - \Gamma\pars{0,1}
=
-\int_{1}^{2}{\expo{-x} \over x}\,\dd x}$. Then
$${\large%
\int_{1}^{\infty}{1 \over x}\,\expo{-x}\pars{\expo{-x} - 1}\,\dd x
=
-\int_{1}^{2}{\expo{-x} \over x}\,\dd x}
$$

The result is surprising !!!. I checked both sides with WA. WA reports the
common value
${\rm Ei}\pars{-1} - {\rm Ei}\pars{-2} = -0.170483$. ${\rm Ei}$ is the
$\it\mbox{Exponential Integral}$ function.

Comment: That's quite a Rube Goldberg way to derive $\int_1^\infty \frac1x e^{-x}(e^{-x}-1)\,dx = -\int_1^2 \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx$. $$\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-2x}}{x}\,dx \overset{u=2x}{=} \int_2^\infty \frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,du.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Quite short. I'm embarrassed. Thanks.